# Please help to hide a div if empty in foreach value

Tags: php

Please can you help me with empty, what to write instead of (!empty (field_value) ? I want to hide all divs when custom field is empty...
Very very thanks! and sorry i am not a programmer ) just a beginner

```
<?php
if(!empty (field_value) ) {  // What to write here?
?>

<div id="rent-term-4">

<?php foreach($custom_fields as $v) {if($v['field_id'] == 61) echo $v['field_value'];}?>

</div>
 <?php
}
?>
```

Comment: So you are trying to output only the value of the custom field with the ID 61 there, and there is only one field with that ID? Then you should output the div tags inside the loop as well (currently you have the opening one before, and the closing one inside the loop, which doesn't make much sense to begin with), and wrap that output into an if condition that checks if `$v['field_value']` is not empty first.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for comments, i just made script onload to hide by css if empty value.

```
if ($("#rent-term-4").is(':empty'))
```